# Why do we take open sets in the hypothesis of The Van-Kampen Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am reading a proof of The Van Kampen Theorem from "Topology: J. R. Munkres, second edition", section - 70, page no - 426. In the hypothesis of the theorem, we assume that the space $X=U \cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$; and $U, V,$ and $ U\cap V$ are path connected. I have gone through the the proof (as given in the text) but I am not able to figure out where the assumption that $U$, $V$ are being open is being used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Step 3, he breaks up an arbitrary path into smaller paths in $U$ or $V$, at that point the Lebesgue number lemma is used and calls for open sets. The same lemma is used later on a homotopy to get condition (1) (uniqueness).

Comment: FYI, there's a closed version of the SVK theorem as well, see page 20 of https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Algebraic_Topology_2011.pdf

Comment: @JustinYoung, I am not able to see how "The Lebesgue number lemma" is being applied here? Moreover, we need $X$ to be a metric space to apply the lemma. But for Van Kampen Theorem, we don't ask for such strong conditions on the space $X$.

Comment: No, the Lemma is applied in the (metric) space $I = [0,1]$, in order to know that you can break up the interval into small enough subintervals so that the path lands in $U$ or in $V$ on each of the subintervals.

Comment: That closed version uses NDR conditions on the closed sets, so there are still open sets floating around.

Comment: @JustinYoung, What is NDR conditions?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract

Comment: or see the reference, it's defined in there. Slightly different meanings, but same general idea.